Python: Delete all vertices from the selected objects
I need a script that deletes all vertices from a group of selected objects.
I intend to merge some other objects to them afterwards to effectively copy their names.
I previously asked how to delete only specific vertices below a certain Y coordinate here:
Python: Delete vertices by coordinates
The solution does work but it takes a pretty long time. I assume bc it has to individually check all the vertices and this are pretty dense meshes. The vertices above the Y coordinate are from objects that get merged into them, so I think that maybe I could just delete all the vertices in the original objects and then merge the other ones without having to worry about coordinates. I assume this would be a lot faster since it only involves selecting everything in edit mode and deleting it.
I've tried modifying the code given in the other question to do what I want but I really don't know what I'm doing when it comes with programming. If anyone can give me a hand that'd be much appreciated.

i am not sure whether i understood what you want: you really wanna delete all (!?) vertices from selected objects? that's what you wrote. Then just select all objects, TAB -> edit mode, A -> select all -> x vertices done.

Yes, but it's part of a larger process where I'm using python to try an automate the whole thing. Atm I'm basically doing just that with a macro and it works fine but it'd be nice if the whole thing could be executed at once instead of having to rely on a mix of activations

you can use this script:
import bpy, bmesh

for ob in bpy.context.selected_objects:

    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

    me = ob.data
    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

    verts = [v for v in bm.verts]

    bmesh.ops.delete(bm, geom=verts)

    bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
    
    
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

Note: this is NOT a clean script. Normally you should ...

ask the ob if it is a mesh object
get the current mode, save that and set it to the current mode back again


Thanks, that works. Not sure what you mean by clean script but it's always going to be used on mesh objects in obj mode so I don't think it'll be a problem
